# Avoid selecting several options on Navigation Drawe

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have a right-side navigation drawer on my application. The drawer contains 4 options. When the user clicks over one of them, the drawer gets closed and some data is fetched in background (the data is shown in a map as markers).

So far, the drawer works correctly. But there is a problem I would like to solve. There is enough time for a user to click over more than an option in the drawer. If that happens, the data is not fetched and the drawer doesn't get closed.

I would like to do the following:

1. The user opens the drawer.
2. The user clicks an option on the
   drawer.
3. All options get disabled, so that the user can't click
   over none of them.
4. The drawer gets closed.

   ...
5. The user opens the drawer
6. Whenever the user wants, return to option 1. to open the drawer again.

I've implemented the following, but it does not work:

```
   private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            final int thePos = position; 

            for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerRightList.getChildCount(); i++){
                View v = mDrawerRightList.getChildAt(i);
                v.setEnabled(false);
                v.setClickable(false);
            }

            mDrawer.setDrawerListener( new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener(){

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                    for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerRightList.getChildCount(); i++){
                        View v = mDrawerRightList.getChildAt(i);
                        v.setEnabled(true);
                        v.setClickable(true);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {

                    boolean wasChecked = !mDrawerRightList.isItemChecked(thePos);
                    //Toast.makeText(homeActivity, "Item pulsado: " + wasChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDrawerRightList.setItemChecked(thePos, !wasChecked);

             ...

             });

             if(mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)){

                 mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerRightList);

             }
```

Is there any way to do so?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit**

Just to clarify: what I want is to prevent the user from clicking more than one option at a time.

**Solution**

Here you are the final solution to my problem:

```
/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements OnItemClickListener {

    private boolean hasClick = false;

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        final int thePos = position; 

        boolean wasChecked = !mDrawerRightList.isItemChecked(thePos);
        mDrawerRightList.setItemChecked(thePos, !wasChecked);

        if(!hasClick){
            hasClick = true;

            for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerRightList.getChildCount(); i++){
                View v = mDrawerRightList.getChildAt(i);
                if(!v.isEnabled())
                    v.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    v.setEnabled(false);
                if(!v.isClickable())    
                    v.setClickable(true);
                else
                    v.setClickable(false);
            }

        }

        switch (thePos) {
            case 0:
                //do stuff

                break;

            case 1:
                //do stuff

                break;  

            case 2:
                //do stuff

                break;

            case 3:
                //do stuff

                break;

            default:
                //do stuff

                break;

        }

        hasClick = false;

        if(mDrawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.END)){

            mDrawer.closeDrawer(mDrawerRightList);
            hasClick = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerRightList.getChildCount(); i++){
                View v = mDrawerRightList.getChildAt(i);
                if(!v.isEnabled())
                    v.setEnabled(true);
                else
                    v.setEnabled(false);
                if(!v.isClickable())    
                    v.setClickable(true);
                else
                    v.setClickable(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting drawer listener inside onItemClick?

Comment: @varum you are right. Thanks for your help, I don't know why I was doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a boolean that change after layout click and change back after the drawer closed.

private  boolean hasClick = false;

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    final int thePos = position; 

    if(!hasClick){
        hasClick = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < mDrawerRightList.getChildCount(); i++){ ...
.
.
 @Override
 public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            boolean wasChecked = !mDrawerRightList.isItemChecked(thePos);
            //Toast.makeText(homeActivity, "Item pulsado: " + wasChecked,   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawerRightList.setItemChecked(thePos, !wasChecked);
            hasClick = false ;
```

Answer (score 1):

1)why not using the **if statment** to know if he pressed and choose a value.
if he does then disable other or hide them or make uncheckable/unclickable

2)or on-press event (click listener(another) to  hide other options :)

3)you already have for what i see everything right so why not add option hide them or make uncheckable/unclickable  for rest of the options ?

sorry for not providing the code but i am a little rusty now for not using eclipse (android coding for very long time)

hope it helped :)

Comment: Yep, I've realised  what you are telling me and I've implemented the if-else statement, enabling and disabling depending on it. But now, afterwards, the drawer remains disabled.

Comment: make sure you didn't wrote the if statement before the choice is happening :)

Comment: you welcome :) no much did just gave tips :) you can do wonders with if statement as long as you don't get lost in all if statements you create hah